# Trying to create app in azure which will post xml to URL based on DML actions in SQL server

Tags: sql, azure, azure-functions

I've tried to trigger azure function whenever there is an Insert, Delete & Update of table in SQL database, am able to trigger azure function using logic app when a new row is inserted, but unable to trigger while some row is deleted\updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to trigger the function by logic app when a new row inserted to the table, you can also create another logic app with the trigger "[When an item is modified (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#when-an-item-is-modified-(v2))" and call your function in this logic app. It will be triggered when the table is updated.

But there is no trigger for delete an item of the sql table currently, you can vote up for this feature in logic app on this [page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/34408159-add-triggers-to-identify-if-row-is-deleted-in-sql).